# error CS1056: Unexpected character `?'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi is there anyone know why im getting that error.

and this is the line im getting the error

```
return (string)row[0] == password && (long)row[1] == 0 && (long)row[2] == 1​;
```

here some code,

```
    if (!Utils.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(account) && !Utils.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password)) 
    {
        List<List<object>> table = ExecuteReader("SELECT password, banned, confirmed FROM accounts WHERE name=@name", new SqliteParameter("@name", account));
        if (table.Count == 1) 
        {
            // account exists. check password and ban status.
            List<object> row = table[0];
            //return (string)row[0] == password && (long)row[1] == 0;
            return (string)row[0] == password && (long)row[1] == 0 && (long)row[2] == 1​;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
            // account doesn't exist. create it.
            ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (@name, @password, 0)", new SqliteParameter("@name", account), new SqliteParameter("@password", password));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You haven't even included a `?` in your code

Comment: there are not so many possible syntactical uses of the ? character in c#, there is the decision operator `condition ? expression1 : expression2`, then there is the safe null `?.` and the coalesce `??`, so I'd recommend to search for ? in the class file. It is obviously not in the code you posted so far.

Comment: Your updated code makes even less sense, `return false` would exit the method, your subsequent `ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (@name, @password, 0)")` would never be called

Comment: This sure looks like passwords are stored in plain text, and that's... it's not good. It really kinda bad, actually. Okay, it's pretty awful.

Comment: @davidl that is exactly the line of code that has the error. **There is a zero-width space character** (unicode 200b) embedded in the code.  Find it and remove it. It's between the `1` and the `;`. Some part of the error reporting code is getting confused and rendering the zero-width space as "?".  How on earth did you get a zero-width space into your editor window? Whatever you did to get it there, *do not do that again*.  As you have discovered, embedding illegal space characters in the code is difficult to detect and fix. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space for details.

Comment: Original poster: Consider entering an issue on the Roslyn github site to alert the C# compiler team that this error message could use improvement. Changing the error message to something like "Unexpected character '?' (Unicode 200B)" would have made this error much easier for you to diagnose yourself.